# Extract unmatched content or values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to extract the un-matched values in data like in (table1)

```
name    id  subject
maria   01  Math computer english
faro    02  Computer stat english
hina    03  Chemistry physics bio
```

The below query

```
Select *
from table1
where subject like ‘%english%’ or 
      subject like ‘%stat%’
```

returns first two rows that are matched with the criteria.

But I just need to extract the un-matched values from column (subject) like below output

```
unmatched
math computer
computer
chemistry physics bio
```

(Because in the first row only math computer values are not matching, in the second row two matches and in third row there are no matches).

can i get that output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With REPLACE you eliminate all occurrences of the values `'english'` and/or `'stat'`:

```
SELECT
  trim(
    replace(replace(replace(subject, 'english', ''), 'stat', ''), '  ', '')
  ) unmatched
FROM tablename;
```

The final trim and replace will remove double spaces from the result and spaces from the start and the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have a poor table design.  You should be storing lists as separate rows in another table -- a so-called "junction" or "association" table.  SQL has a great data type for storing lists.  It is called a "table" not a "string".

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other peoples really, really bad choices of data model.

If so, you can use `replace()` and `trim()` to get the list you want.  I would do:

```
SELECT trim(replace(replace(' ' || subject || ' ', ' english ', ' '
                           ), ' stat ', ''
                   ), '  ', ' '
           ) as unmatched
FROM tablename;
```

This easily generalizes to more values, without worrying about introducing adjacent spaces.